# Is it Possible to Lock or Encrypt SVG Graphics?

Tags: html, webkit, svg

I am looking into building a web portfolio using SVG graphics, the portfolio is primarily aimed at modern Webkit Smartphone/Tablets. I'd comtemplating the use of SVG, for sharpness and animation properties, but I'm just wondering it it possible to **LOCK** or **ENCRYPT** an SVG? to protect my graphics for copyright purposes?

Thanks

K

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a word, No. Images are the answer there.

The browser needs the full path for the object at some point and anyone will be able to intercept that.

If you really don't want to just use images, then make sure you include the license with the source. All you really need is google and a lawyer. Any sufficiently complex svg file is [searchable](https://www.google.ca/search?q=56.23%20C387.73%2054.23%20386.73%2049.23%20389.23%2048.73%20zM383.23%2059.73%20C385.73%2058.73%20393.23%2060.23%20392.73%2063.23)

Comment: Cheers Andrew, that's what I thought - that's how SVG's works on Icon repository http://thenounproject.com